# Java ArrayList compiling on machine but not on school system

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, compiler-errors

My assignment was to create an ArrayList that keeps track of a stores sales every day and posts which ever customer spent the most.  I completed the assignment, so I thought.  All three of the classes compile on Eclipse and in my terminal window.  However when I upload them into my school's system and then test, I'm getting an error thrown in a class.  Needless to say this is frustrating and confusing to me, someone who is very new at this.  It's some kind of issue with the syntax of my ArrayList but I can't figure it out because it's working fine on Eclipse. :/

The error I'm getting is:

```
Store.java:17: illegal start of type
customers = new ArrayList<>(); \\the up arrow is under the ">"
```

The code is as follows.

```
//******************************************
// Store.java 
// Written...
// 2013
//*******************************************

//===========================================
// Store class holds ArrayList of customers
//===========================================

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Store {private List<Customer> customers; //stores customers

public Store() {
    customers = new ArrayList<>();
}

//creates new customer for arraylist
public void addSale(String customerName, double amount) {
    Customer c = new Customer(customerName, amount);
    customers.add(c);
}

//finds the best customer
public String nameOfBestCustomer() {
if (customers.isEmpty()) {
    return "No customers are stored!";
} else {
    Customer best = customers.get(0);

    for (Customer c : customers) {
        if (c.getAmount() > best.getAmount()) {
            best = c;
        }
    }
    return best.getName();
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Java 7 at home and at school you're compiling with Java 6 since the diamond operator is only valid for Java 7.

Solution: either use Java 7 for both, or make sure that your code is compliant with Java 6.

i.e., change this:

```
customers = new ArrayList<>();
```

to this:

```
customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```